# Attaching a pre-built query to a scoped_session in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I'm receiving a weird error, `AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute '_autoflush'`, when attempting to execute a pre-built query on a scoped_session in the SQLAlchemy ORM.

I'm using a context manager to yield a scoped_session,

```
@contextmanager
def connect(my_session_factory):
    session = scoped_session(my_session_factory)
    try:
        yield session
    except Exception as exception:
        session.rollback()
        raise exception
    finally:
        session.close()
```

and then am using it like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query

query = Query(my_model).offset(my_offset).limit(my_limit)
with connect(my_session_factory) as session:
    instances = query.with_session(session).all()
    return instances
```

This, however, raises the exception above.

I note also that queries of the form `session.query(my_model)` work just fine.

Where am I going wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay - I don't have an answer to the question as posed, but I do seem to have a workaround.

The issue appears to be with the proxying behaviour of the `scoped_session` object. As I understand it, the `scoped_session()` method takes a `sessionmaker` object and uses that to create thread-local `session` object. The `scoped_session()` method, however, does not return this thread-local `session`. Instead it returns a `scoped_session` object that in some way (on which I'm not entirely clear) houses the thread-local `session`. To access this thread-local session directly, you can do `scoped_session.registry()`, or instead simply `scoped_session()` where `scoped_session` here is a `scoped_session` *object* that has been returned by the `scoped_session` method.

```
my_scoped_session = scoped_session(my_session_factory)
my_local_session = my_scoped_session()
```

Now here's the issue: the documentation seems to suggest that calls such as `my_scoped_session.query(...).all()` and `my_local_session.query(...).all()` are equivalent, thanks to the proxying behaviour of the `scoped_session` object. I have found this to be true for the most part, however not so in my original problem case.

If you do `my_query = Query(...)` (i.e. build a non-session bound query), and then attach that to a `scoped_session` object (hoping to take advantage of the `scoped_session` proxying machinery, such that `my_query` is handled in the context of the `scoped_session` thread-local `session`), by way of `my_instances = my_query.with_session(my_scoped_session).all()` or similar, you get the traceback in my original question.

My workaround is to skip over the `scoped_session` object's proxying machinery altogether, and instead to bind the `my_query` directly to `my_local_session`.

```
my_query = Query(...).filter(...).sort(...)
my_instances = my_query.with_session(my_local_session).all()
```

This seems to work out. If, however, anyone would care to chime in on the dangers (if any?) of working with `scoped_session(my_session_factory)()` directly, rather than with `scoped_session(my_session_factory)` (which most online tutorials seem to do), then I'd be grateful!